# Query Elasticsearch documents using the size of an array field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a property of type array `names` for some type `customer` in `Elasticsearch`. I want to create a mapping for this type so that I can query customers using the length of the array by creating an extra field for this property `size`.

The following query is the desired query to achieve:

```
# Search for data using the size of the array [DESIRED, NOT WORKING]
GET example-index/customer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "names.size": {
        "value": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried the `keyword` analyzer with the `token_count` type for this field but it didn't work out:

```
# Create index with mapping
PUT example-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "customer": {
      "properties": {
        "names": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "size": {
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# Create some data
POST example-index/customer/1
{
  "names": [
    "a b",
    "c d e f",
    "g h i j k l"
  ]
}
```

I know that I can query for the length using the `script` query but using an extra field would be much better for me:

```
# Search for data using the size of the array [WORKING, NOT DESIRED]
GET example-index/customer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['names'].values.length == 3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The [ingest API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) allows Elasticsearch to transform the document before it is indexed.